# applying c# generics to fine tune the code

Tags: c#

I have written a code to generate chart data for the [Highcharts library](http://dotnet.highcharts.com) and need to know if there are any improvements possible. I have applied generics but think it could be fine tuned further. Could somebody recommend anything?

I have basically written a *GenerateBoxPlotChartSeries* method that would generate *BoxPlotChartSeries* as the name suggests.

There are two methods that have the same name accepting different parameters. Is it a good idea to have two different methods or is it better to have a common method and apply generics to the parameter and then check based on the parameter and execute the *if* *else* condtion within the method? My only worry is that the length of the method would go on increasing. Also note that I would be creating more graphs like Line Chart and Spline Chart. The classes and methods need to take this into consideration as well. So the method will also need to Generate spline chart data and line chart data accordingly

Please note the following
1. NpvGraphs would contain CommIns,CaptiveIns,SelfIns and EVAGraphs would contain CaptiveView and ParentView.

2. I have defined BloxPlotSeries data for BloxPlot chart. Similarly I would need to define additional classes for spline chart and line chart. Assume they have different properties while suggesting better coding standards in your answer.

I would be soon incorporating other charts apart from *boxplotchart*. How do I handle that?

```
 public class Series<T>
    {
        public List<T> data { get; set; }
    }

 public class BloxPlotSeriesData
    {
        [JsonMinify]
        public double low { get; set; }

        [JsonMinify]
        public double q1 { get; set; }

        [JsonMinify]
        public double median { get; set; }

        [JsonMinify]
        public double q3 { get; set; }

        [JsonMinify]
        public double high { get; set; }

        [JsonMinify]
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }

  public class NPVGraphData
    {
        [JsonMinify]
        public List<double> CommIns { get; set; }
        [JsonMinify]
        public List<double> CaptiveIns { get; set; }
        [JsonMinify]
        public List<double> SelfIns { get; set; }
    }

 public class EVAGraphData
    {
        [JsonMinify]
        public List<double> CaptiveView { get; set; }
        [JsonMinify]
        public List<double> ParentView { get; set; }
    }
```

Calls to the method

```
NpvResult = new Models.NpvResults()
{
  SeriesData = GenerateBoxPlotChartSeries(trigger2Output.NpvResults.GraphData)

}


 EvaResult = new Models.EvaResults()
 {
 SeriesData =GenerateBoxPlotChartSeries(trigger2Output.EvaResults.GraphData)
}
```

Similarly I am going to have two more calls to the method that will generate spline chart and line chart accordingly. The method call above only does for BoxPlotChart.

```
StressResult = new Models.StressTestAnalysis()
{
SeriesData=GenerateSplineChartSeries(trigger2Output.StressTestAnalysis.GraphData)
}

    EndingSurplus = new EndingSurplus()
    {
      SeriesData=GenerateLineChartSeries(trigger2Output.EndingSurplus.GraphData)
    }
```

Methods

```
  private Series<BloxPlotSeriesData> GenerateBoxPlotChartSeries(EVAGraphData evaResultsGraphData)
        {

            //CaptiveView
            var captiveViewSeriesData = new BloxPlotSeriesData
            {
                low = evaResultsGraphData.CaptiveView[0],
                q1 = evaResultsGraphData.CaptiveView[1],
                median = evaResultsGraphData.CaptiveView[2],
                q3 = evaResultsGraphData.CaptiveView[3],
                high = evaResultsGraphData.CaptiveView[4],
                Color = "#C111A0"

            };

            //ParentView
            var parentViewSeriesData = new BloxPlotSeriesData
            {
                low = evaResultsGraphData.ParentView[0],
                q1 = evaResultsGraphData.ParentView[1],
                median = evaResultsGraphData.ParentView[2],
                q3 = evaResultsGraphData.ParentView[3],
                high = evaResultsGraphData.ParentView[4],
                Color = "#FFB81C"

            };
            return new Series<BloxPlotSeriesData>
            {
                data = new List<BloxPlotSeriesData> { captiveViewSeriesData, parentViewSeriesData }
            };
        }

        private Series<BloxPlotSeriesData> GenerateBoxPlotChartSeries(NPVGraphData npvResultsGraphData)
        {
            //CaptiveIns
            var captiveInsSeriesData = new BloxPlotSeriesData
            {
                low = npvResultsGraphData.CaptiveIns[0],
                q1 = npvResultsGraphData.CaptiveIns[1],
                median = npvResultsGraphData.CaptiveIns[2],
                q3 = npvResultsGraphData.CaptiveIns[3],
                high = npvResultsGraphData.CaptiveIns[4],
                Color = "#C111A0"
            };

            //CommIns
            var commInsSeriesData = new BloxPlotSeriesData
            {
                low = npvResultsGraphData.CommIns[0],
                q1 = npvResultsGraphData.CommIns[1],
                median = npvResultsGraphData.CommIns[2],
                q3 = npvResultsGraphData.CommIns[3],
                high = npvResultsGraphData.CommIns[4],
                Color = "#FFB81C"
            };
            //SelfIns
            var selfInsSeriesData = new BloxPlotSeriesData
            {
                low = npvResultsGraphData.SelfIns[0],
                q1 = npvResultsGraphData.SelfIns[1],
                median = npvResultsGraphData.SelfIns[2],
                q3 = npvResultsGraphData.SelfIns[3],
                high = npvResultsGraphData.SelfIns[4],
                Color = "#5D63D3"
            };
            return new Series<BloxPlotSeriesData>
            {
                data = new List<BloxPlotSeriesData>{ captiveInsSeriesData, commInsSeriesData, selfInsSeriesData }
            };

        }
```

Comment: Ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: CaptiveIns/CaptiveView and CommIns/ParentView look suspiciously similar in terms of use (of course their type is equal). What makes them different?

Comment: Their type is equal but from UI perpective they are different. Hence NpvGraphs would contain CommIns,CaptiveIns,SelfIns and EVAGraphs would contain CaptiveView and ParentView

Comment: Alright, so I would treat them as different classes just like you did and that would suffice to make their difference clear; no need to make the name of their properties different unless you have other reasons. I also edited my code to simplify some details and make it more readable. Is it ok for you or you still look for generics?

Comment: Class Series initially wasn't a generic class . I made that a generic one. Does that make sense ?

Comment: I have updated my post . Could you please once again go through it

Comment: CaptiveView and ParentView cannot be in abstract class as it doesn't make sense right?

Comment: Making a class generic means that you are planning to pass in different datatypes (int, double, strings, whatever). If you are going to make calculations, you must also deal with conversions: if you pass in strings you will have to detect it and possibly deal with globalization issues (what if your regional settings use a comma as decimal separator, but the user provides a dot)? Also, do you really need different datatypes? If you are going to perform all calculations as doubles, what is the reason to allow e.g. strings? Plus yes, your methods might become long and full of switch or if-else.

Comment: CaptiveView can be in the abstract class because, unless you show what makes it functionally different from CaptiveIns or doesn't have an equivalent property in other subclasses, it is common among different subclasses and automatically inherited. If its name in the abstract class disturbs you, you can rename it CaptiveElements. You already have classes to differentiate the meaning of your data, why to change the name of your properties if functionally are equal?

Comment: I understand where you are coming from the reason why  i created separate properties is for s new developer to understand how it relates to the UI section. I agree that fundamentally they all are holding list of double values but do we distinguish them for code clarity ? What are your thoughts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166377/discussion-between-tom-and-francesco-b).

Comment: Also as mentioned in the post , I would be having additional charts like spline charts and line charts . Currently I have method called generatebloxchartseries. Similary I would need a methods GenerateSplineChartSeries and GenerateLineChartSeries which will be taking different datas as parameters. Currently not defined. How do I incorporate that?

Comment: it depends. Every textbook will say that if the drawing methods will be "a few", let's say max 4, you can add them inside the abstract class and override them (if necessary) in your subclasses. On the opposite, if your methods can become "a lot", then it's better e.g. to create one static class per method and pass it to the concrete classes, implementing the strategy pattern. Or, in a simpler fashion, move them inside a static "helper" class if they share some logic.

Comment: Did you discover anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you really need generics because your job seems rather specialized and not very "generic": you need to extract plot data from classes that share a certain structure. 
Perhaps a simple class hierarchy would do?
All I did was:

- Renaming common properties and "pull them up" in an abstract class, which has methods to manipulate common data (i.e. the shared properties *CaptiveView* and *ParentView*
- Create a virtual method to provide more data if a subclass supports it, as it's the case with *SelfIns*
- Change the case of public properties, as they should be uppercase unless your team follows different guidelines
- Isolate specific values into private constants, so to have a better idea of what you are going to use inside your class (among other reasons)
- Make *GenerateBoxPlotChartSeries* a "bird's-eye" method, i.e. a method that gives you a quick idea of what's going on without implementation details
- Create two private (smaller) methods, *GetCaptivePlotData* and *GetParentData* that hold implementation details.

  - EDIT: Put all methods inside the abstract class so they will be easier to read, have less parameters and make sense in terms of OOP

Let me know if you have questions or suggestions.

```
public class Series<T>
{
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}

public class BloxPlotSeriesData
{
    [JsonMinify]
    public double Low { get; set; }

    [JsonMinify]
    public double Q1 { get; set; }

    [JsonMinify]
    public double Median { get; set; }

    [JsonMinify]
    public double Q3 { get; set; }

    [JsonMinify]
    public double High { get; set; }

    [JsonMinify]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// The base class, holding common drawing data.
/// </summary>
public abstract class GraphData
{
    private const string CaptivePlotColor = "#C111A0";
    private const string ParentPlotColor = "#FFB81C";

    [JsonMinify]
    public List<double> CaptiveView { get; set; }
    [JsonMinify]
    public List<double> ParentView { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override this method in subclasses if you needto provide additional data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>More data to be plotted.</returns>
    public virtual BloxPlotSeriesData ReturnMoreData()
    { return null; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns plot data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Plot data.</returns>
    public Series<BloxPlotSeriesData> GenerateBoxPlotChartSeries()
    {
        BloxPlotSeriesData captiveViewSeriesData = GetCaptivePlotData();
        BloxPlotSeriesData parentViewSeriesData = GetParentData();

        var Result = new Series<BloxPlotSeriesData>
        {
            Data = new List<BloxPlotSeriesData> { captiveViewSeriesData, parentViewSeriesData }
        };

        return AddMoreData(Result);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds more data if the first argument can provide it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Result"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Series<BloxPlotSeriesData> AddMoreData(Series<BloxPlotSeriesData> Result)
    {
        var MoreData = ReturnMoreData();
        if (MoreData != null)
        {
            Result.Data.Add(MoreData);
        }
        return Result;
    }

    private BloxPlotSeriesData GetParentData()
    {
        return new BloxPlotSeriesData
        {
            Low = ParentView[0],
            Q1 = ParentView[1],
            Median = ParentView[2],
            Q3 = ParentView[3],
            High = ParentView[4],
            Color = ParentPlotColor
        };
    }

    private BloxPlotSeriesData GetCaptivePlotData()
    {
        return new BloxPlotSeriesData
        {
            Low = CaptiveView[0],
            Q1 = CaptiveView[1],
            Median = CaptiveView[2],
            Q3 = CaptiveView[3],
            High = CaptiveView[4],
            Color = CaptivePlotColor
        };
    }
}

public class EVAGraphData : GraphData
{
}

public class NPVGraphData : GraphData
{
    [JsonMinify]
    public List<double> SelfIns { get; set; }

    public override BloxPlotSeriesData ReturnMoreData()
    {
        return new BloxPlotSeriesData
        {
            Low = SelfIns[0],
            Q1 = SelfIns[1],
            Median = SelfIns[2],
            Q3 = SelfIns[3],
            High = SelfIns[4],
            Color = "#5D63D3"
        };
    }
}
```